# How to solve set theory equation question

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The universal set $U = \{\text{natural numbers from $1$ to $100$}\} \cdot X \subseteq U \cdot n(X) = 12.$ Determine $n(X’).$

Since $X$ is the subset of the universal set from natural numbers from $1$ to $100$ you simply subtract $100 -cdot (12) = 88.$

So $n(X’)=88.$

Comment: What does any of that notation mean?  What is $\{\text{natural numbers from 1 to 100}\}\cdot X$ mean?  What does $U\cdot n(X)$ mean.  If $U$ is the universal set how can it be a subset of another set $U\cdot n(X)$ what ever that is is.  And what is equal to $12$.  Is "$12$" a set and that is what the set $U\cdot n(X)$ is equal to and is claiming $u = \text{set }A\subseteq \text{set }B = 12$ a run-on sentence?  I don't know what you are talking about.  And what does $X'$ mean and what does $n(X')$.

Comment: Or is it three sentences?  Sentence 1: The universal set is $U=\{1,2,3....,100\}$.  Sentence 2:  $X\subseteq U$.   Sentence $n(X)=12$?  What does $n(A)$ mean?  Does that mean how many elements does $A$ have?.   "Determine $n(X')$.  What does $X'$ mean? Does that mean the compliment of $X$.  "you simply multiply 100⋅(12)=1200"  Why are you multiplying?  If the universal set has $100$ elements no set can have more than $100$ elements.  So why are you multiplying?  Can you tell me in your words what the problem is that you are doing and what you think it means?

Comment: have you ever learned set theory

Comment: I know quite a lot about set theory.  But I don't know what you mean by the symbols you are typing on your keyboard.  That is why I am asking.  Let's start with what do those $\cdot$s mean?  Are the periods? Do they mean multiplication?  Are the a form of set inner products?   And what does the $'$ mean in your text.  Does it mean the complement?  Or some other meaning?  (Most texts will use $X^c$ or $\overline X$ to mean compliment but $X'$ is not unknown).  And what does $n(X)$ mean? If you text uses some symbols it doesn't mean *other* text do.

Comment: ok so in the equation:  The universal set U = {natural numbers from 1 to 100}• X ⊂ U• n(X) = 12. Determine n(X’).   The X represents a subset for U which is for the universal set, the n=number and the apostrophe ' on X means everything but not X so X prime,some call it so the question is asking to determine the n(X') when n(X)=12

Comment: @fleablood,how would you determine this:https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/XZAT-C6Tch-BurZN70lCQR1c_P3oIcPM9PB-qozg4UwBKQE59gd7Yx9EwqR6J5F337TVBIe8o0lNiARm1aDhCX64o1bvNWf9KzWzPzHAIZ3Keb3ogGlnLAYZiTgu=w740

Comment: And what do those big dots mean?  Periods?  Spaces between concepts?...  Anyway he Henno Brandsma's answer is the correct answer and it is absolutely clear and perfect.  There are $100$ elements in the universal set.  $X$ contains $12$ of those elements.  So $X'$ will contain all then elements not in the set $X$.  And $X$ has $12$ elements and $U$ has $100$ total the $X' = U\setminus X =\{$ all the elements in the universal set that *aren't* is $X\}$ will have all the elements *but* those $12$.  So $X'$ will have $100 - 12 = 88$ elements.  Completely straightforward.

Comment: yes,And do you know the answer to this question: https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/XZAT-C6Tch-BurZN70lCQR1c_P3oIcPM9PB-qozg4UwBKQE59gd7Yx9EwqR6J5F337TVBIe8o0lNiARm1aDhCX64o1bvNWf9KzWzPzHAIZ3Keb3ogGlnLAYZiTgu=w740. I think its B because complement is everything but P

Comment: I needed help with it because 'Im not entirely sure,And it wouldn't let me post it,so If you could help that wold be really great @fleablood

Answer (score 1):

$U$ has $100$ elements. $X$ which is a subset of $U$ has $12$ elements. $X'$ (I assume this means the complement of $X$ (in the universe $U$), it's a notation I've seen before) thus has $100-12= 88$ elements. So $n(X')= 88$.